# EmEditor 21.1.1 でウインドウ横幅を広げておいて垂直分割時、右ウィンドウの表示が空、クリックすると位置ずれ、が発生します。

Tags: emeditor

いつも大変お世話になっておりまして、ありがとうございます。

障害内容は、タイトルに書いたとおりで
「EmEditor 21.1.1 でウインドウ横幅を広げておいて垂直分割時、右ウィンドウの表示が空、クリックすると位置ずれ、が発生します。」です。

垂直分割前に、テキスト表示の「指定文字数折り返し」が「[94|>92]」で、マウスでウィンドウの横幅を
左右表示できるようにその倍以上のコラムに拡大しておいてから操作しました。

[image: 末尾のみ連番の30行のファイルの例：垂直分割、水平分割、右下ウィンドウクリック後の状態です]

・動作環境
同様の3システムすべてで発生しました。

Windows 10 64bit 最新Update実施済
EmEditor 21.1.1 : 現在の最新
および
EmEditor 21.1.902 : 現在のベータ版の最新（いま試してみました）

・再現性はこちらでは100%。

・そのひとつ前のEmEditorバージョンで発生していたかどうかは不明です。
その前ぐらいまでは毎日頻繁に使っていて、正常でした。

・表示位置ずれの場合に、この例の右下のように、
水平スクロールバーが表示されないことがあります。
　そのときマウスカーソルでドラッグすることで、
左端（ＡＢＣ…）までスクロールして表示されました。

・あらかじめウィンドウの横幅をマウスで拡大していないときは、右ウィンドウが空表示にはなりませんが、表示先頭コラムがずれました。

・毎日多用する機能なので、いまかなり不便をしています。

ご多忙中と存じますが、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

これは表示上の問題ですが、次のバージョンでは修正されます。次のベータ版 `v21.1.903` が公開されたらをお試しください。

Comment: 早速お調べくださって修正の目処もお示しくださってありがとうございます。「表示上の問題」と教えていただいたので、表示乱れが起こってもクリックやドラッグで直しながら、ファイルは正常であると安心して使うことができます。次のベータ版で修正を確認してみたいと思います。

Comment: v21.1.903 は公開されました。

Comment: 本件が修正されたというベータ版 **v21.1.903** をインストールし、正常動作を確認いたしました。ありがとうございます。正式版のリリースをお待ちいたします。

Comment: ベータ版 v21.1.904 でも、本件動作OKです．

Comment: ベータ版 v21.1.905 でも、本件の修正は正常動作しました。

Comment: ベータ版 v21.1.906 でも、本件の修正は正常動作しました。

Comment: v21.1.2 がリリースされ、本件の修正は正常動作しました。安心して利用できます。このたびは急いで確実に修正してくださって、ありがとうございました。完了のチェックを入れます。